# Configure Traefik from command line completely

Tags: traefik

I have a need to add configuration to backends and endpoints in a simple command line args. I see how you add entry points but I do not see how to add backends.

If any one has an example it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution that doesn't require a `traefik.toml` file to configure frontends and backends?

Comment: Not as of yet trying to jump in to get into the Traefik project to maybe build this out a little nicer in the project through contribution.